In flutter I want a page, that shows a text, a whole pdf and another text. How can I do this?
The problem is, that in every pdf renderer library, if I put the pdf view in SingleChildScrollView widget, I always get this error: FlutterError (RenderConstrainedOverflowBox object was given an infinite size during layout.

I want to achieve the left version!!!
This is how I solved now, but I think that this solution is not very clean.... Can someone give me a nice solution?
class _PdfPageState extends State<PdfPage> {
  bool pdfDownloaded = false;
  late double pdfHeight;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadPdf();
  }

  void loadPdf() async {
    PdfDocument doc = await PdfDocument.openAsset('assets/hello.pdf');
    if (mounted) {
      double width = MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width;
      setState(() {
        pdfDownloaded = true;
        pdfHeight = doc.pageCount * width * 1.28;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          const Text("Before pdf"),
          !pdfDownloaded
              ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
              : SizedBox(height: pdfHeight, child: PdfViewer.openAsset('assets/hello.pdf')),
          const Text("After pdf"),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


I understand, and okay, I set in the backend, that the pdf must have less that 10 pages. but the question still remains, how can I show the whole pdf, without this ugly solution:
pdfHeight = doc.pageCount * width * 1.28;
